# Android SDK Manager fails to run

Tags: java, android, environment-variables

I know this question has been asked before, possibly many times, but none of the answers have helped my problem.

The problem I'm having is that after following the installation instructions here, http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html, When I get to the point of running the SDK Manager a command prompt windows appears then closes immediately after. I have tried following install directions from other sites, and even followed all of the suggestions I have found in what threads I could find on here.

I am trying to do this on Windows 7 Ultimate 64Bit, and have tried setting the Path as described in other posts. The java version I have is 6u35.

This is what the Android.bat file says when it is run.

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3550 or
swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:328)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:316)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:118)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:101)
Press any key to continue . . .`
```

I'm not sure what it means, or how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried to add JAVA_HOME=<java installation path> in env.variables?

Comment: You should  try it. My workstation has JAVA_HOME env. variable and my android sdk manager works well.

Comment: no, the java is 32 bit. without it I can't even get the sdk to install.

Comment: Install the 64 bit of java, then set the JAVA_HOME=<location of java 64-bit>

Comment: It didn't work for me. Is there a certain location the SDK should be installed to?

Comment: SDK Location shouldn't have space 

for ex. C:\Android\android-sdk-windows

Comment: Should I intalls the JRE along with the JDK or is the JDK alone enough?

Comment: JDK Contains JRE, don't worry about it. Install JDK by default

Comment: I guess it's just something to do with the 64 bit OS, it works flawlessly on my 32bit windows 7 Pro desktop, and in my 32bit win 7 Pro VM.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update SWT from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/#SWT.

For example:

- ..\tools\lib\x86\swt.jar <= swt-4.2.1-win32-win32-x86.zip\swt.jar
- ..\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar <= swt-4.2.1-win32-win32-x86_64.zip\swt.jar

Answer (score 0):

It is a permissions problem. For those who are having the same problem in Win7/Win8, right click on eclipse.exe then select "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

I try several way to solve this problem and only this way solve my problem. tanks

This is easy and works just fine!

The solution:
　　The eclipse folder
　　swt-gdip-win32-4236.dll
　　swt-win32-4236.dll

Copy to system32 folder, and rename"…-3550"
Et voila!

http://www.programering.com/a/MDO4YDNwATA.html

Answer (score -1):

This is easy and works just fine!

The solution:
　　The eclipse folder
　　swt-gdip-win32-4236.dll
　　swt-win32-4236.dll

Copy to system32 folder, and rename"…-3550"
Et voila!

http://www.programering.com/a/MDO4YDNwATA.html